# Numpy: find index of elements in one array that occur in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 1D arrays and I want to find out if an element in one array occurs in another array or not.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([ 1, 48, 50, 78, 85, 97])
B = np.array([38, 43, 50, 62, 78, 85])
```

I want:

```
C = [2,3,4] # since 50 in second array occurs in first array at index 2, 
            # similarly 78 in second array occurs in first array in index 3,
            # similarly for 85, it is index 4
```

I tried:

```
accuracy = np.searchsorted(A, B)
```

But it gives me undesirable results.

Answer (score 15):

You could use `np.where` and `np.in1d`:

```
>>> np.where(np.in1d(A, B))[0]
array([2, 3, 4])
```

`np.in1d(A, B)` returns a boolean array indicating whether each value of `A` is found in `B`. `np.where` returns the indices of the `True` values. (This will also work if your arrays are not sorted.)

Answer (score 6):

You should start with `np.intersect1d`, which finds the set intersection (common elements) between arrays.

```
In [5]: np.intersect1d(A, B)
Out[5]: array([50, 78, 85])
```

To get the desired output from your question, you can then use `np.searchsorted` with just those items:

```
In [7]: np.searchsorted(A, np.intersect1d(A, B))
Out[7]: array([2, 3, 4])
```