# Finding indices of matches of one array in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, A and B. A conatains unique values and B is a sub-array of A.
Now I am looking for a way to get the index of B's values within A.

For example:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B = np.array([1,7,10])
# I need a function fun() that:
fun(A,B)
>> 0,6,9
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) -

```
np.nonzero(np.in1d(A,B))[0]
```

You can also use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), if you care about maintaining the order -

```
np.searchsorted(A,B)
```

For a generic case, when `A` & `B` are unsorted arrays, you can bring in the `sorter` option in `np.searchsorted`, like so -

```
sort_idx = A.argsort()
out = sort_idx[np.searchsorted(A,B,sorter = sort_idx)]
```

I would add in my favorite [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) too in the mix to solve a generic case -

```
np.nonzero(B[:,None] == A)[1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [125]: A
Out[125]: array([ 7,  5,  1,  6, 10,  9,  8])

In [126]: B
Out[126]: array([ 1, 10,  7])

In [127]: sort_idx = A.argsort()

In [128]: sort_idx[np.searchsorted(A,B,sorter = sort_idx)]
Out[128]: array([2, 4, 0])

In [129]: np.nonzero(B[:,None] == A)[1]
Out[129]: array([2, 4, 0])
```

Comment: This assumes we don't care about order; it returns the same results for B=[1,7,10] as for [1, 10, 7].  (The OP's question doesn't specify either way.)

Comment: @DSM Helpful comments! Thanks! Made it generic.

Comment: the docs suggest to use now [`isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) instead of `in1d`

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried `searchsorted`?

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B = np.array([1,7,10])

A.searchsorted(B)
# array([0, 6, 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: If the values in `A` are non negative and reasonably small:

```
lookup = np.empty((np.max(A) + 1), dtype=int)
lookup[A] = np.arange(len(A))
indices  = lookup[B]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question these days. However, the timing performance is very critical for me. Therefore, I guess the timing comparison of different solutions may be useful for others.

As Divakar mentioned, you can use `np.in1d(A, B)` with `np.where`, `np.nonzero`. Moreover, you can use the `np.in1d(A, B)` with `np.intersect1d` (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901311/numpy-find-index-of-elements-in-one-array-that-occur-in-another-array#:%7E:text=You%20should%20start%20with%20np.intersect1d%2C%20which%20finds%20the%20set%20intersection%20(common%20elements)%20between%20arrays.) page). Also, you can use `np.searchsorted` as another useful approach for sorted arrays.

I want to add another simple solution. You can use the comprehension list. It may take longer that the previous ones. However, if you take the advantage of [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) python package, it is much less time-consuming.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: from numba import njit

In [3]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
In [4]: b = np.array([1,7,10])

In [5]: np.where(np.in1d(a, b))[0]
   ...: array([0, 6, 9])

In [6]: np.nonzero(np.in1d(a, b))[0]
   ...: array([0, 6, 9])   

In [7]: np.searchsorted(a, b)
   ...: array([0, 6, 9])


In [8]: np.searchsorted(a, np.intersect1d(a, b))
   ...: array([0, 6, 9])

In [9]: [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x in b]
   ...: [0, 6, 9]

In [10]: @njit
    ...: def func(a, b):
    ...:     return [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x in b]

In [11]: func(a, b)
   ...: [0, 6, 9]
```

Now, let's compare the timing performance of these solutions.

```
In [12]: %timeit np.where(np.in1d(a, b))[0]
4.26 µs ± 6.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit np.nonzero(np.in1d(a, b))[0]
4.39 µs ± 14.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit np.searchsorted(a, b)
800 ns ± 6.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit np.searchsorted(a, np.intersect1d(a, b))
8.8 µs ± 73.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x in b]
15.4 µs ± 18.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [17]: %timeit func(a, b)
336 ns ± 0.579 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```