# Find index of multiple elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array of integers, I need to find the indexes of many of its elements stored in a different array. This is:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([ 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 86, 9, 15])
a2 = np.array([ 2, 3, 5, 6, 9])
```

Where `a1` is my initial array of elements, and `a2` is the array that contains the elements for which I need their indexes in `a1`.

In this case, the result should be:

```
a3 = ([4, 5, 1, 2, 8])
```

This seems like a rather simple operation, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Indeed this looks like a duplicate of that question. Sorry I missed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may try this:

```
In [378]: (a1[:, None] == a2).argmax(axis=0)
Out[378]: array([4, 5, 1, 2, 8], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: This solution works, but it a lot slower than `np.nonzero(a2[:, None] == a1)[1]` given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678543/finding-indices-of-matches-of-one-array-in-another-array