# Matplotlib - Highlight points from already plotted graph using only Y-coordinate

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I have some stock data and I plotted the data `index = x-axis`, `price = y-axis` and now after calculating I have found an array of price i.e sub array of price. I want to highlight the points in the array on the graph

I have tried `markvery()` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html#introductory) but cant understand its working.
Here is my code

```
from matplotlib
import pyplot as plt


x =[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7] # array to be plotted
y=[100,111,112,111,112,113,114] # array to be plotted

subArray = [111,114] # array to be highlighted
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? Do you want those points to be a different color?

Comment: you could just plot again on top of the first plot

Comment: @JordanSinger Yes

Comment: @BanishedBot Yes I can do that but is there any matplotlib way of doing this because if I do this manually I have to traverse the whole dataset to find the index of the price an then plot

Comment: Mind that the memers of the `subarray` do not necessarily need to be unique inside the initial `y` array. So there is no "general" solution to this. What you should do instead is to review how you created the `subArray` in the first place and store together with it a list of the respective indices (and/or values from `x`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subArray contains two points which occur more than once in your `y`. So first you can get the indices of your subArray elements from y and then plot them separately again to highlight them. As [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) pointed out, there is no in-built general approach for this.

That being said, things become easier if you convert to NumPy array. Below is one way to find the indices among others listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678543/finding-indices-of-matches-of-one-array-in-another-array)

```
import numpy as np

x =np.array([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) # array to be plotted
y=np.array([100,111,112,111,112,113,114]) # array to be plotted

subArray = [111,114] 
ids = np.nonzero(np.in1d(y, subArray))[0]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x[ids], y[ids], 'bo')
```

[image]